# CentOS 8 Mingw Compile Error with cc1plus

Tags: centos, configuration, c++, mingw

I recently setup a fresh install of CentOS 8 to use the Mingw Compiler for C++ (I believe it's removed from CentOS 7).

Everything was installed as follows

```
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum --enablerepo=PowerTools install mingw32-gcc
yum --enablerepo=PowerTools install mingw64-gcc
```

Which did give me the commands I wanted both `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` (specifically for targeting Windows builds)

I am unable to use them though because calling both on a simple cpp file gives the error

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I can still compile for Linux with the `g++` command though without any issue but what am I missing to be able to use the Mingw compilers?

*UPDATE*

By the way this CentOS 8 is running in Docker, I don't know if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re compiling C++ code, so the frontend is looking for the C++ compiler. `mingw{32,64}-gcc` only provides the C compiler, you need to install the C++ compiler too:

```
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install mingw{32,64}-gcc-c++
```

Comment: Wow amazing, is the compile command still the same? `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`

Comment: Yes, `gcc` chooses the language based on the file extension. You can use `...-g++` instead if you prefer; it makes it more obvious that you intend to compile C++.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my issue